# NoSuchMethodException when retrieve method by reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, types

I am trying to get a class method by is name, e.g.:

```
case class A(i : Int) {def geti = i}
val a = A(123)

val met = a.getClass.getMethod("geti")
```

This seems to work, but if I try to do the same on a Double:

```
val a:Double = 3.0
a.getClass.getMethod("toString")
```

I run into this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: double.toString()
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
```

Could you help me figuring out what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for the `abstract final class scala.Double`:

> Double, a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point number (equivalent to Java's
>   double primitive type) is a subtype of scala.AnyVal. Instances of
>   Double are not represented by an object in the underlying runtime
>   system.
>
> There is an implicit conversion from scala.Double =>
>   scala.runtime.RichDouble which provides useful non-primitive
>   operations.

So scala `Double`s only have a `toString()` method by virtue of an implicit conversion into `RichDouble`, and the class `Double` itself does not contain this method.